# Bootbox validation error message not appear in firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, bootbox

The title describe the problem and I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkkyoun/mwhkgoy8/7/) to show the issue.

```
$("input[name='delete']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {

      // form validation
      if (document.getElementById("student_delete_form").reportValidity()) {
         $('#student_delete_form').submit();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Expected Result:** Validation error message on both chrome and firefox

**Actual Result:**  Validation error message only appear on firefox but not chrome

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It turns out that the if statement should be before the bootbox

```
$("input[name='delete']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // form validation
  if (document.getElementById("student_delete_form").reportValidity()) {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
      if (result) {
        $('#student_delete_form').submit();
      }
    });

  }
});

$('#student_delete_form').on('submit', function() {
  alert('I am submitted!');
})
```

I have also update the fiddle for anyone who encounter the same issue as me